# Expression for $1-\sin x$

Tags: trigonometry

Do we take $1-\sin x$ as $(\sin \frac{x}{2}-\cos \frac{x}{2})^2$ or $(\cos \frac{x}{2}-\sin \frac{x}{2})^2$. My teacher says that in most of the cases we take the latter. In one problem the interval was specified as something like $(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi)$ and my teacher told me to take the former. I am facing problem in understanding this. Can someone shed some light on this? Also what about $1+\sin x$.

Both the expressions may be the same but they yield different results (in differentiation and integration problems) and I have myself seen this.

Comment: $(a-b)^{2} = (b-a)^{2}$, hence I don't understand why it is even bothering you.

Comment: @AnikBhowmick, Both may be the same but they yield different results.

Comment: What is the context of this question? If I were to see "$1-\sin x$" in the wild, I'd leave it as-is; re-writing in either suggested form just adds visual and mental clutter. However, if I had $\sqrt{1-\sin x}$, then it would certainly be convenient to identify the expression as a square in order to cancel the radical. In this case, you could still use either suggested form, since you need to wrap it in absolute value bars anyway; however, the latter has a *sliver* of an advantage, in that you can drop the absolute value bars when you know $x$ happens to be acute.

Comment: Is this question related to taking square roots?

Comment: One of the problems did involve square roots.

Comment: *"One of the problems did involve square roots."* Please show us some of these problems ... especially ones where the different choices "yield different results". It's easier to give advice when we know just exactly how the advice needs to be applied.

Comment: I don't exactly remember the problem now.

Comment: Problem arises if you take the square roots.

Answer (score 0):

Those expressions are equal so... Both. Regarding the last question, plug $x \mapsto -x$ and you'll have an almost equal expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$\sin^2(x/2)+\cos^2(x/2)-2sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)=1-\sin(x)$$ and $$(\sin(x/2)+\cos(x/2))^2=1+\sin(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

For any real number $x$, you have that 
$$x^2 = (-x)^2 $$

Since
$$\sin\frac x2 - \cos \frac x2 = -\left(\cos \frac x2 - \sin\frac x 2\right)$$

The two expressions, (1):
$$\left(\sin\frac x2 - \cos \frac x2\right)^2 $$
and (2):
$$\left(-\left(\cos \frac x2 - \sin\frac x 2\right)\right)^2 = \left(\cos\frac x2 - \sin\frac x 2\right)^2 $$
are equal.

Since they are the same, they cannot yield different results. An error must have been made. Unless I'm misunderstanding what exactly is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

As for real $a,\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$ which will be $=+a$ if $a\ge0$

Now $1-\sin2y=(\cos y-\sin y)^2=2\sin^2\left(\dfrac\pi4-y\right)$

Now $\sin u\ge0$ if $u$ lies in the first & second quadrant

Similarly, $(\sin y+\cos y)^2=?$